# InputQuery on IOS Rad Studio 11 Modal Response Reversed

Tags: ios, delphi, user-input, rad-studio

I am working with RAD Studio Delphi 11 Version 28.0.44500.8973 with Update 1 and the PAServer update on Windows 10.

When I use the `TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery()` method under iOS, the modal response from the Input query is reversed.

When the OK button is pressed, the modal result (`AResult`) is 2 (`mrCancel`) and the resulting response is not updated.

When the Cancel button is pressed, the modal result (`AResult`) is 1 (`mrOK`) and the resulting response is returned.

This is completely opposite to the way it is supposed to work.

When the method is used under Android or Windows, the modal result and response are correct.

This was working properly in RAD Studio 10.4, and I believe was working properly when I first installed RAD Studio 11. However, I since had to reload RAD Studio 11, so I downloaded the latest install that had Patch 1 included and then loaded the PA Server Patch.

I have attached the code to a very simple project that demonstrates the behaviour.

I haven't been able to find any posts on this issue other than one back in 2017 where the Cancel button wasn't working under Windows, but I'm pretty sure that is not relevant here.

Just wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same issue, or if it is something from my install or setup. I duplicated the RAD Studio 11 install on my development laptop, and I'm getting the same issue.

I am attaching code to a very simple project that recreates the issue.

Unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.DialogService.Async,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    chkFlipIOSResponse: TCheckBox;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OnInputQuery_Close(const AResult: TModalResult; const AValues: array of string);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery('Enter Text', ['Enter Text:'], [label1.Text], Self.OnInputQuery_Close)

end;

procedure TForm1.OnInputQuery_Close(const AResult: TModalResult; const AValues: array of string);
var Response: String;
begin
  Label2.Text := 'Modal Response = ' + IntToStr(AResult);

  Response := AValues[0];

{$IFDEF IOS}
  if AResult = 1 then
     Label3.Text := 'Cancel Button Pressed'
   else
     Label3.Text := 'OK Button Pressed';
{$ELSE}
  if AResult = 1 then
     Label3.Text := 'OK Button Pressed'
   else
     Label3.Text := 'Cancel Button Pressed';
{$ENDIF}

  Label1.Text := Response.Trim;
end;

end.
```

Form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 282
  ClientWidth = 338
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 118.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 190.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Label1: TLabel
    Position.X = -8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 145.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 338.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    Text = 'Message Response'
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object chkFlipIOSResponse: TCheckBox
    Position.X = 96.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 234.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 19.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 4
    Text = 'Flip IOS Response'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Position.X = -8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 107.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 338.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    Text = 'Modal Response'
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Position.Y = 75.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 338.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 17.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    Text = 'Button Pressed'
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same issue

Yes, I have seen several people report a similar issue.  And I found several Quality Portal tickets related to it:

[RSP-11101: InputQuery on iOS wrong value for ModalResult](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11101)

[RSP-37702: InputQuery result problem on iOS](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37702)

[RSP-38143: iOS inputQuery returns wrong button](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38143)

[RSP-38454: FMX: TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery ModalResult wrong](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-38454)

Comment: Thanks @Remy. Dave Nottage's solution from RSP-3772 solved my issue. I only did a Google search and didn't think of searching the Quality portal separately. I will keep it in mind for next time. I could have saved myself some time.